# How do I modify this truth table so that it uses and displays 1's and 0's rather than true and false

Tags: java, boolean, truthtable

How do I modify this truth table so that it uses and displays 1's and 0's rather than true and false.

```
public class Table {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        boolean p,q;

        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

        p = true;
        q = true;

        System.out.print(p+"\t"+q+"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q)+"\t"+(p|q)+"\t");
        System.out.println((p^q)+"\t"+(!p));

        p = true;
        q = false;

        System.out.print(p+"\t"+q+"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q)+"\t"+(p|q)+"\t");
        System.out.println((p^q)+"\t"+(!p));

        p = false;
        q = true;

        System.out.print(p+"\t"+q+"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q)+"\t"+(p|q)+"\t");
        System.out.println((p^q)+"\t"+(!p));

        p = false;
        q = false;

        System.out.print(p+"\t"+q+"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q)+"\t"+(p|q)+"\t");
        System.out.println((p^q)+"\t"+(!p));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, there exists **no** logical xor operator, only one for *bitwise* operations!

See [Oracle.com - Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) as reference


Anyway, here your desired conversion from `true` and `false` Strings to `1` and `0`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT(p)");

    printTable(true, true);
    printTable(true, false);
    printTable(false, true);
    printTable(false, false);
}

private static void printTable(final boolean p, final boolean q) {
    System.out.printf("%s\t", p    ? "1" : "0");
    System.out.printf("%s\t", q    ? "1" : "0");
    System.out.printf("%s\t", p&&q ? "1" : "0");
    System.out.printf("%s\t", p||q ? "1" : "0");
    System.out.printf("%s\t", p^q  ? "1" : "0");
    System.out.printf("%s\t", !p   ? "1" : "0");
    System.out.printf("\n");
}
```

Output is

```
P       Q       AND     OR      XOR     NOT (p)
1       1       1       1       0       0   
1       0       0       1       1       0   
0       1       0       1       1       1   
0       0       0       0       0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to have a function `toDigit(boolean value)` which returns 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`; this could then be used in the print commands rather than just printing the boolean values, e.g.

```
System.out.print(toDigit(p)+"\t"+toDigit(q)+"\t");
System.out.print(toDigit(p&q)+"\t"+toDigit(p|q)+"\t");
System.out.println(toDigit(p^q)+"\t"+toDigit(!p));
```

Comment: Do i have to import this function to make it work ? As it comes up with red lines

Comment: You have to write the `toDigit` function. It's very short though - it takes a boolean and if the boolean is `true` it would return `1` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Still unable to visualise or understand how to write , could you modify the table to show me how it's done ?

Comment: There's no need to modify the table itself. At the bottom of the class (just before the last `}`) you'd have to add a new function which would look something like this: `private static int toDigit(boolean value) { ... }`. Rather than `...` in there you have to return a `1` if `value` is true and `0` otherwise. If you don't know how to write functions, check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html and if you don't know how to do something dependent on a boolean value try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0):

one simple way is :

```
boolean flag;
//...
System.out.println(flag ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple challenge from the book "Java: A Beginner's Guide - Fifth Edition" by Herbert Schildt. Therefore, I see no problem in giving the complete solution. Below is an adaptation courtesy of blalasaadri's suggestion.

```
public class Table {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean p, q;

        // below is an alternative truth table in binary form (0s and 1s)
        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

        p = true; q = true;
        System.out.print(toBinary(p) + "\t" + toBinary(q) + "\t");
        System.out.print(toBinary(p&q) + "\t" + toBinary(p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println(toBinary(p^q) + "\t" + toBinary(!p) + "\t");

        p = true; q = false;
        System.out.print(toBinary(p) + "\t" + toBinary(q) + "\t");
        System.out.print(toBinary(p&q) + "\t" + toBinary(p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println(toBinary(p^q) + "\t" + toBinary(!p) + "\t");

        p = false; q = true;
        System.out.print(toBinary(p) + "\t" + toBinary(q) + "\t");
        System.out.print(toBinary(p&q) + "\t" + toBinary(p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println(toBinary(p^q) + "\t" + toBinary(!p) + "\t");

        p = false; q = false;
        System.out.print(toBinary(p) + "\t" + toBinary(q) + "\t");
        System.out.print(toBinary(p&q) + "\t" + toBinary(p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println(toBinary(p^q) + "\t" + toBinary(!p) + "\t");
    }

    // this method exchanges true for 1, and false for 0 
    private static int toBinary(boolean value) {
        if(value == true)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```